# C MPI array passing

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

Why can't I access muhray 8 lines from the bottom?  The print lines that start with "!!" work correctly but I can't seem to get the right values at the very end.

Here is my output:

```
[computer@node01 ~]$ mpiexec -n 8 ./presum 1000
!! proc0's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc0's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc2's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc2's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc3's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc3's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc1's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc1's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc4's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc4's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc5's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc5's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc6's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc6's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
!! proc7's array is size 125 and goes from 1 to 1
proc7's array is size 125 and goes from 4693173 to 1819307369
```

Here is the code in question:

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    //max size of the data array to split up
    #define MAXSIZE 1000000

    //methods
    int checkInput(int nprocs, int argc, char *argv[], int id);

    //mpi send & rec tags
    int ARSIZE = 0;     //array size
    int ARR = 1;        //array
    int MSM = 2;        //slave sum

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int     ARsize;             /*size of the array to pre-sum*/
        int     id;                 /*process id number*/
        int     nprocs;             /*number of processors*/
        int     i, j, k;            /*counters*/
        int     muhsize;            /*size of personal array to calculate*/
        int     * muhray;           /**/

        //MPI framework
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        //pull input, check values, return ARsize
        ARsize = checkInput(nprocs, argc, argv, id);

        //set up array, serial run, send out chunks
        if (!id) {      

            //variables only the zero node needs
            int     data[ARsize];               /*full original array of numbers*/
            int     chunkSize, upper, lower;    /*vars to determine cunksize to send out*/
            int     smoothCount = 0;            /*BOOL for uneven division chunksize*/

            //fill array with numbers
            for (i = 0; i < ARsize; i++) {
                data[i] = 1;
            }

            //sequential solution here      


            //determine chunkSize
            chunkSize = (int) (ARsize/nprocs);  
            if (ARsize % nprocs != 0) {
                chunkSize = chunkSize + 1;
                smoothCount = 1;
            }

            //send chunks of data to procs
            for (i = 0; i < nprocs; i++) {          
                lower = i * chunkSize;
                upper = ((i+1) * chunkSize) - 1;
                if (i == nprocs-1 && smoothCount == 1) {
                    upper = ARsize-1;
                }
                int intarray[(upper-lower)];
                for (k = lower, j = 0; k <= upper; k++, j++) {
                    intarray[j] = data[k];   
                    }
                if(i > 0) {
                    //send array size
                    MPI_Send(&j, 1, MPI_INT, i, ARSIZE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    //send actual array
                    MPI_Send(intarray, j, MPI_INT, i, ARR, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
                }
                //zero no send to self, this data used later for all nodes calc
                else {
                    muhsize = j;
                    int muhray[muhsize];
                    for (j = 0; j <= chunkSize; j++) {
                        muhray[j] = intarray[j];
                    }   
                    printf("!! proc%d's array is size %d and goes from %d to %d\n", id, muhsize, muhray[0], muhray[(muhsize-1)]);
                }
            }       
        }
        else {

            MPI_Recv(&muhsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, ARSIZE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            int muhray[muhsize];
            MPI_Recv(muhray, muhsize, MPI_INT, 0, ARR, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("!! proc%d's array is size %d and goes from %d to %d\n", id, muhsize, muhray[0], muhray[(muhsize-1)]);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        printf("proc%d's array is size %d and goes from %d to %d\n", id, muhsize, muhray[0], muhray[muhsize]);
        fflush(stdout);
        //MPI_Send(&muhsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MSM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);       


        MPI_Finalize();

    }

//pull input, check values, return ARsize
int checkInput(int nprocs, int argc, char *argv[], int id) {

    int size;

    if (nprocs % 2 != 0 || nprocs == 6 || nprocs > 8) {
        if (!id) printf("run with 2^k procs, (1 >= k <= 3)\n");  
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }
    if (argc != 2) {
        if (!id) printf("Usage: presum [array size (max: %d)]\n", MAXSIZE);
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);        
    }
    size = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (size <= nprocs) {
        if (!id) printf("search range must be greater than processor count\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }
    if (size > MAXSIZE) {
        if (!id) printf("array size must be less than or equal to %d\n", MAXSIZE);
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the definition of `int checkInput(int nprocs, int argc, char *argv[], int id);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is very likely with scopes of variables. For instance here:

```
...
else {
    MPI_Recv(&muhsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, ARSIZE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    int muhray[muhsize];
    MPI_Recv(muhray, muhsize, MPI_INT, 0, ARR, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("!! proc%d's array is size %d and goes from %d to %d\n", id, muhsize, muhray[0], muhray[(muhsize-1)]);
    fflush(stdout);
}

printf("proc%d's array is size %d and goes from %d to %d\n", id, muhsize, muhray[0], muhray[muhsize]);
```

you declare `int muhray[muhsize];` inside the scope of the `else` construct. When you exit this scope `muhray` is destroyed as it is a local variable. What you are using in the last `printf` seems to be an uninitialized `int  * muhray;` declared immediately after the main.

Note that while they have the same name these two are **different** variables.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're printing "muhray[(muhsize-1)]" twice and "muhray[muhsize]" at the end. You shall always print the value of "muhray[(muhsize-1)]".

The else-part with the two MPI_Recv calls uses a locally defined variable called "muhray", which is different from that defined initially in the main function (it actually shadows the muhray defined at the beginning of the main function). Thus "printf("!!..." uses a completely different variable than the last "printf("proc..." call.

Comment: Just as correct with the other guy, thanks... wish I could give you both a green check.